# symfony 2 composer line command

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I have little problem with updating bundle in symfony 2
I installed composer to do it but composer seems doesn't work correctly. No matter what I put in command line, composer shows version, available commands and that's all. Nothing more. Doing nothing. Did somebody have similar problem?

Jacob

Comment: Which operating system?  Can you run symfony console commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What SO do you use? If you use Windows try open cmd and type this:

```
composer
```

this command shows you information about Composer, if it does not, you need add the route in the Environment Variables (Variable: Path).

Comment: I have such path C:\composer\composer.phar
I have added C:\composer to PATH enviroment in Windows but command composer running from CMD doesn't work

Comment: try this: `php composer.phar`  otherwise you can create a bat file. called composer.bat. in the same folder. this file (composer.bat) should contain @ECHO OFF
php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*

Comment: thank you. Now everything is ok. I updated my xampp, I installed composer from windows setup application not thru the cmd and curl. Path variable has been set and now everything works well. Thank you!